# Transform a "for...in...break" loop into a "while" loop

Tags: iphone, ios, computer-science

Can I transform this loop in a while loop ?

```
int i=0;
for (NSDictionnary *crossArrayDictionnary in (NSArray *)mainArray) {
    //some code...
    i++;
    if (i>=50) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: why? You still need to check two conditions (the array length and the 50)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
NSInteger max, i = 0;
max = [mainArray count] < 50 ? [mainArray count] : 50;

while (i < max) {
    NSDictionary *crossArrayDictionnary = [mainArray objectAtIndex:i];
    // You code here.   
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what is the most efficient method ? The for or the while ?

Comment: The `for` with the `in array` statement, because it will use fast enumeration.

Comment: @Nielsou the `for in` construction is called Fast Enumeration. I guess it's faster :) http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html

Answer (score 2):

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [mainArray objectEnumerator];
NSDictionary *crossArrayDictionnary = nil;

while ((crossArrayDictionnary = [enumerator nextObject])) {

    //some code...
    i++;
    if (i>=50) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know objective-c, but something like this:

```
int i=0;
while (i < 50 && i < [mainArray count]) {
    NSDictionary *crossArrayDictionnary = [mainArray objectAtIndex:i];
    //some code...
    i++;
}
```

Comment: cant get an item with the [] you need to call objectAtIndex.

Answer (score 0):

As rckoenes said,
Minor change.

```
NSInteger i = 0;
while (i < 50 && [itemsMutable cout] >= i) {
    NSDictionary *crossArrayDictionnary = [itemsMutable objectAtIndex:i];
    // You code here.   
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Its better to do the count before hand and not in the if, this will call the count every time it loops.